# List of arrays into .txt file without brackets and well spaced

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to save .txt file of a list of arrays as follow :

```
list_array =
    
[array([-20.10400009,  -9.94099998, -27.10300064]),
 array([-20.42099953,  -9.91499996, -27.07099915]),
 
 ...
```

This is the line I invoked.

```
np.savetxt('path/file.txt', list_array, fmt='%s')
```

This is what I get

```
[-20.10400009  -9.94099998 -27.10300064]
[-20.42099953  -9.91499996 -27.07099915]
 
 ...
```

This is what I want

```
-20.10400009 -9.94099998 -27.10300064
-20.42099953 -9.91499996 -27.07099915
 
 ...
```

EDIT :

It is translated from Matlab as followed where I .append to transform

```
Cell([array([[[-20.10400009,  -9.94099998, -27.10300064]]]),
       array([[[-20.42099953,  -9.91499996, -27.07099915]]]),
       array([[[-20.11199951,  -9.88199997, -27.16399956]]]),
       array([[[-19.99500084, -10.0539999 , -27.13899994]]]),
       array([[[-20.4109993 ,  -9.87100029, -27.12800026]]])],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really see what is wrong with your code, except for the missing imports. With `array`, do you mean `numpy.array`, or are you importing like `from numpy import array` (which you should refrain from doing)?

Running this example gives exactly what you want.

```
import numpy as np

list_array = [np.array([-20.10400009,  -9.94099998, -27.10300064]),
 np.array([-20.42099953,  -9.91499996, -27.07099915])]

np.savetxt('test.txt', list_array, fmt='%s')
```

```
> cat test.txt
-20.10400009 -9.94099998 -27.10300064
-20.42099953 -9.91499996 -27.07099915
```

Comment: Before each inputs you have`np.array()` I only got `array()`

Comment: Where does `array()` come from? As far as I know, this is not a standard function in python, so it's taken from some module. I'm assuming `numpy` - so `np.array()` is the same as `array()`. @Yuji

Comment: I add an edit screen

Comment: That is how `numpy` arrays are printed. In that case, your code should work, and I'm not sure why it doesn't. How is `list_array` written in your code? @Yuji

Comment: It is translated from Matlab cell that's why, But I can't figure how to come back into pythonic way